# Closing resources that may throw exceptions

Tags: java, exception

- Get a `Connection` from the pool (this may throw an exception)
- Create a `Statement` out of the connection (also may throw an exception)
- Execute an SQL query using that statement and store it in a `ResultSet` (can throw as well)
- Do stuff with the query results
- Close `ResultSet` (exception!)
- Close `Statement` (exception!)
- Close `Connection` (exception!)

---

Look at this code:

```
    Connection  conn = null;
    Statement   st   = null;
    ResultSet   set  = null;
    try {
        conn    = Database.getConnection();
        st      = conn.createStatement();
        set     = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM THING");

        // <-- Do stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        // Close set if possible
        if (set != null) {
            try {
                set.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        // Close statement if possible
        if (st != null) {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        // Close connection if possible
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

---

The `finally` block is where I close my stuff. As you can see, it is very messy. My question would be: is this the right way to clean up those resources?

Comment: Guava's `Closer` can emulate try-with-resource in Java 6  http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/09/13/java-7-automatic-resource-management/ - And the countless `closeQuietly(Closable)` methods may help to write your code snippet shorted (although only semi-correct because exceptions while closing resources may mean that write operations failed and should therefore not be ignored).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is the proper way of catching exceptions for closeable resources, prior to Java 1.7, except that you should catch `SQLException` instead of `Exception`.

Starting in Java 1.7, you can use [the "try-with-resources" statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which allows you to declare resources that will have `close()` called automatically when the `try` block finishes, saving boilerplate `finally` code.

```
try (Connection conn = Database.getConnection(); Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet set = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM THING")) {
   // Your "try" code as before
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   // Handle as before
}
// No "finally" to clean up resources needed!
```

Comment: should he really use try with resources? because in the case where everything works except the close, try-with-resources will throw the on-close exception, where the posted code won't.

Comment: @NathanHughes Ignoring exceptions in not problematic here since it's just a read operation, which mostly don't throw while closing anyways. I guess that's why try-with-resource has no built in way to ignore closing errors although they are indeed pointless to the application logic once it could read the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

Look into try with resources, if you can (needs at least Java 7) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is but you can make it look nicer  by writing code (preferably in a utility class) which is reusable

```
public static void close(Statement st) {
    if (st != null) {
        try {
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```

and use this method in your finally block. Add similar methods for `Connection` and `ResultSet`